# How can I use my chromebook in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, adb, google-chrome-os, android-debug, androidappsonchromeos

I tried to use my Acer Chromebook tab to debug my app in Android Studio but I have some troubles ...

I followed this documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment#debug_with_adb
The last command I typed is "sudo ectool usbpd 0 dr_swap"

And when I type sudo "ectool usbpd 0", I have this : 
"Port C0: enabled, connected State:SNK_DISCOVERY Role:SNK UFP, Polarity:CC1"

I have nothing in Android or when I use sdk tools with the command "adb devices", the list is empty.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I cannot edit my post ... I forgot the "hello" ..! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your question that you are attempting to debug using USB rather than using ADB over network.  Since you mentioned that you are using an Acer Chromebook, I do not believe that they support USB debugging (based on this [Chromium Document](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-adb-debugging-over-usb)).

Instead, what I would encourage is that you utilize ADB over network instead (don't forget to put your laptop in [developer mode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/developer_mode.md)).